# Is there a way to render diferent components depending on language selection using i18n?

Tags: reactjs, i18next

I'm building an application with react, using i18next for the internationalisation.
I need to change my banner depending on the language selected by the user. Is there a way to do this using this internationalisation framework?

Currently im using useTranslation for all the strings onf my site and it works fine, wat im lookinf for next, is to render diferent thing depending on the language selection. Something like this.

````
import React from "react"
import { useTranslation } from "gatsby-plugin-react-i18next";
import Layout from "../components/layout"

const IndexPage = () => {
  const { t } = useTranslation("home");

  return (
    <Layout>
     {eng ? (
       <div className="EngDiv">
            <p className="regularP">{t("areyouinterested")}</p>
       </div>       
     ):(
       <div className="EspDiv">
            <p className="regularP">{t("areyouinterested")}</p>
       </div>     
      )}
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default IndexPage```
````

Answer (score 0):

You could just dynamically choose the component according to the language. If you assign a component to a variable with a capital first letter, you can use it as a component:

```
const IndexEng = ({ t }) => (
  <div className="EngDiv">
    <p className="regularP">{t("areyouinterested")}</p>
  </div>
);

const IndexEsp = ({ t }) => (
  <div className="EspDiv">
    <p className="regularP">{t("areyouinterested")}</p>
  </div>
);

const IndexPage = () => {
  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation("home");
  const Index = i18n.language === "es" ? IndexEsp : IndexEng;

  return (
    <Layout>
      <Index t={t} />
    </Layout>
  );
};
```

If you have multiple languages, one idea would be to use an object and index it with the language:

```
const IndexEng = ({ t }) => (
  <div className="EngDiv">
    <p className="regularP">{t("areyouinterested")}</p>
  </div>
);

const IndexEsp = ({ t }) => (
  <div className="EspDiv">
    <p className="regularP">{t("areyouinterested")}</p>
  </div>
);

const indexComponents = {
  en: IndexEng,
  es: IndexEsp,
  // ...
};

const fallback = IndexEng;

const IndexPage = () => {
  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation("home");
  const Index = indexComponents[i18n.language] ?? fallback;

  return (
    <Layout>
      <Index t={t} />
    </Layout>
  );
};
```